# What is the bandwidth per second of this scenario?

Tags: video-streaming, streaming-flv-video

If I have a video chat application with 10 users all visible to each other and the upstream and downstream rates are at 1MBs. Is the bandwidth used per second 10 * 1MBs * 2 (upstream and downstream) = 20MBs? Just trying to understand streaming.

Answer (score 0):

It should depend on streaming protocol. If multicast protocol is available it should be less, otherwise it may be much larger than you have calculated.